# if $ax-2by+cz=0$ and $ac-b^2>0$ , Prove $zx-y^2\leq0$

Tags: inequality

> for real numbers like $a,b,c,x,y,z$ that $ax-2by+cz=0$ and $ac-b^2>0$ Prove:$$zx-y^2\leq0$$
>
> Additional info: The Proof should be by contradiction.we can use Cauchy , AM-GM and other simple inequalities.

*Things I have done so far:* as Problem wants a Proof by contradiction, I assume that $zx-y^2>0$ and later show that it is impossible.We know that $ac-b^2>0$. So $$ac+zx-(b^2-y^2)>0$$

by AM-GM we know that $$b^2+y^2\geq 2by$$

So $$ac+zx-2by>0$$

and by $ax-2by+cz=0$ we can write $$ac+zx-ax-cz>0$$

and I stuck here. and another problem about my uncompleted proof is using AM-GM.because the question did not mentioned about being positive real number.it just said real numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$zx-y^2\le0?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee,the book says it is $xy-y^2\leq0$.However it maybe a typo in book.could you explain why you thought it is wrong?

Comment: How to eliminate $z?$

Comment: you are right. it would take a while for me to edit the question.

Comment: The proposition seems to be wrong if I'm not wrong as derived in my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that $by=\frac{ax+cz}{2}$, so that

$$
acy^2 \geq b^2y^2=\bigg(\frac{ax+cz}{2}\bigg)^2 \geq ax\times cz 
$$

and hence $y^2 \geq  xz$ (notice that $ac>0$ because $ac>b^2$).

Answer (score 3):

It seems **user2838619** and **Ewan Delanoy** 
already gave correct solutions with elementary inequalities.
Still the following viewpoint may be of interest, connecting the result with the
[Schur
product theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem).

Assume on the contrary that $zx-y^2 > 0$.
The inequality $ac-b^2$ is equivalent to the statement
that the symmetric matrix $M := \left({a \; b \atop b \; c}\right)$ has
positive determinant, and thus that either $M$ or $-M$ is positive definite.
Likewise $zx-y^2 > 0$ means either $N := \left({x \; y \atop y \; z}\right)$
or $-N$ is positive definite.  By Schur it follows that Hadamard product
$$
M \circ N = \left( {ax \ \ by \atop by \ \ cz} \right)
$$
is either positive or negative definite.  This contradicts the hypothesis
$ax-2by+cz = 0$, because
$$
ax - 2by + cz = (1,-1) \left( {ax \ \ by \atop by \ \ cz} \right) (1,-1)^T
= \big\langle (1,-1), \ (M\circ N) (1,-1)^T \big\rangle.
$$

Comment: i didn't know the Schur product theorem, but that is a very neat and instructive answer. (not to take anything away from Ewan's excellent brief answer, and Lab's initial clarification of the question)

Answer (score 1):

If $x,y$ are of opposite sign, $y^2>zx,$ and we are done

Again $ac-b^2>0\iff ac>b^2\ge0\implies a,c$ are of same sign

So, we need to consider $a,c$  & $x,z$ in pair are same sign

Case $(1):$ $a,c>0; z,x>0$

Case $(4):$ $a,c<0; z,x<0$

$$2by=ax+cz\ge2\sqrt{aczx}\implies b^2y^2\ge aczx>b^2zx\iff b^2(y^2-zx)>0\iff y^2>zx$$

Case $(2):$ $a,c<0; z,x>0$

Case $(3):$ $a,c>0; z,x>0$

$$2by=ax+cz\le2\sqrt{aczx}$$

As $ax,cz<0,$

this $\displaystyle\implies b^2y^2\ge aczx>b^2zx\iff b^2(y^2-zx)>0\iff y^2>zx$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following equation.
$$axt^2-2byt+cz=0.$$
Since $ax-2by+cz=0$, we see that this equation has root $1$, which gives
$$b^2y^2-acxz\geq0.$$
Since $ac>b^2$, we obtain $ac>0$ and since
$$acy^2\geq b^2y^2\geq aczx,$$ we obtain
$$acy^2\geq aczx,$$
which gives $y^2\geq zx$.

Done!